# Adding arrays and finding the largest number

Tags: c#, arrays

[image]
How would you solve that question?
Background: beginner in C# who has only studied for a couple of days.

```
int[] nums= new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
        string strnum = Console.ReadLine();
        nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(strnum);
    }
}
sum(nums);
Biggest(nums);
...
Got stuck here while doing the above question
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is not a _please do my homework_ site.

Comment: I think you can figure out how to compute the total yourself. You need to do addition *foreach* of the numbers in the array ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following functions to your program and call it a day (if you wanna be cheeky):

```cs
static void Sum(int[] nums) => Console.WriteLine($"Sum: {nums.Sum()}");
static void Biggest(int[] nums) => Console.WriteLine($"Biggest: {nums.Max()}");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int[] nums= new int[10];
int? maxNum = null;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number:");
        string strnum = Console.ReadLine();
        nums[i] = Convert.ToInt32(strnum);
        maxNum = (maxNum == null || maxNum < nums[i]) ? nums[i] : maxNum;
    }
}
```

You can read the new line as: if maxNum is null (it's first empty state) or if maxNum is minor than the last number, then maxNum is the last number. Else, maxNum is still maxNum.

This is just one way to do it.
Good luck!